# Way To Search Content

Tags: views, path-aliases, redirection

I am new to Drupal and am currently trying to edit some pages on a site I inherited. The site does not seem well-organized as there is a panoply of URL redirects and aliases. As a result, I am having a difficult time finding the right pages to edit.

Is there a way to just search for the path and have it return the right content to edit? Perhaps there is a module for that?

As an example, I have a page www.example.com/donate which needs to be edited. When I look under aliases and URL redirects, "donate" returns nothing. How can I go about finding this particular page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, sorry that your first experience is with a poorly organized site. Like any powerful tool Drupal can do some really annoying things when poorly setup, and it's frustrating when you start with a messy project.

A page may be pulling in content from a node, a view, a form, a block, or some other source. Depending on how careful the original theme developer was, for any page not providing an edit tab you may find there is a contextual menu (or several) hiding under a light grey gear icon (usually at the top right of the element is supports). Those will often provide hints about where the content is coming from, or even direct links to edit it.

It can also be useful to look over the list of views on the site (Structure --> Views), which is Drupal's query builder. The displays frequently have headers and footers defined along side the query.

After that you'll probably want to figure out what is used to organize elements on the site's pages. Drupal 7 provides several tools to do that (sometimes used together which can cause confusion) check the modules list for Panels, Display Suite, and Context.  Whichever is enabled you'll want to research a bit. Each can help pull content into a page, Panels may even be setup to provide some of that content itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not all Drupal paths end with a content (or node) page. For example, the D7 core Contact module has the path **/contact**, but in order to "edit" it you need to change administration pages within the admin section (**/admin...**) or a theme template if you're wanting to change how the HTML is rendered.

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the `menu_router` (D7) or `router` (D8) database table. These DB tables contain static/dynamic paths (the `path` column) with additional metadata about what/how these paths rendered. They should help you discover what controls paths that aren't node or node alias paths.

Comment: Is "menu_router" the name of the module? I am trying to install it using Drush but cannot seem to find it.

Comment: I think I found it in DB.

Comment: `menu_router` is a _database table_ that's installed by Drupal core (system module).

Comment: Is there a good way to search nodes?

Comment: **node/%** is the path that handles nodes. If you're looking for aliases, check the `url_alias` table.